# shifts in Baer*-rings

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, baer-rings

Let $A$ be a Baer*-ring with the unit $1$. An  important point that holds in every Baer*-ring is this: for every element $y\in A$ there is an smallest projection $e_y\in A$, called the left projection of $y$,  satisfying in $e_yy=y$.

We say $x\in A$ is a shift if $x^*x=1$ and  there exists a sequence of pairwise orthogonal projections $\{p_n\}$ such that:

1. $\sup_{n\geq1} \sum_1^n p_k=1$.
2. $p_n=e_{xp_{n-1}}$.

Q. Let $x$ be a shift. For a finite projection  $q$ in $A$, I guess $q\wedge e_{x^*q}$ should be  strictly less than $q$, however I have no clear proof!

Comment: Wouldn't $q=0$ be a counter-example to the question?  Or does "finite projection" somehow imply that $A$ is infinite-dimensional, and you want the kernel to be finite dimensional?

Comment: @Pace Nielsen  Thanks. Actually $q$ is a non-zero finite projection.